# HPLIP send fax via PHP

Tags: ubuntu, fax, cups

I wanted to integrate the fax function on a HP MFP that we bought with php app developed in house.

However, I found that the fax utility, hp-sendfax, although allowing command line options, works if I run from out Ubuntu server desktop, it refused to work when I tried from Sah session to our Ubuntu server from my Mac.

Is there anyone who know how to get it work in pure command line mode?

Comment: when I run hp-sendfax from remote server ssh command line, the following shows up:

error: Unable to lock /home/itadmin/.hplip/hp-systray.lock. Is hp-systray already running?
warning: Unable to connect to dbus. Is hp-systray running?
error: Unable to initialize dBus. PC send fax requires dBus and hp-systray support. Exiting.

Answer (score 1):

The hp-sendfax app is a python app, though I dont have the right equipment to test, it seems you want to not run in GUI_MODE (see var mode == GUI_MODE) and this does seem like it can be set from args, but bar that open the file and just before the first place where 'if mode == GUI_MODE:' occurs you set 'mode = NON_INTERACTIVE_MODE'

Hope this wors for you. Else if you do php, see what hp-sendfax does, from a quick scan it looks like it is connecting to dbus which you guys might do from php directly.